# Displaying toast when spinner item is selected

Tags: android, toast, android-spinner

I have created a spinner. When an item is selected, I want to show a toast, which will show what was selected. How can I do that?

Comment: Try to find a solution yourself first please. Spend 5 minutes googling spinners and you'll have your answer. Try "android spinner selected"

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. It's works fine for me:

```
    Spinner spinnerone = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterone = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mtype2);
    spinnerone.setAdapter(adapterone);
    spinnerone.setSelection(0);
    spinnerone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        { 
             int item = spinnerone.getSelectedItemPosition();
             y = mtype2[item];
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
   });
```

Comment: in it, y should be a string. But don't think y is a string here. Also, couldn't GET THIS mtype2.Can  you please clarify? I am beginner in android, so don't know much.

Comment: In here mtype2 is an string array containing items & y is a String

Comment: Did you debug your application? Just debug, after you'll get where the exact error raising and let me know

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at onItemSelected

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html provides everything you need to know about the Toast functionality of Android.

Comment: Actually I am able to get toast message in beginning. But I want it to be displayed every time I select one among list.

Comment: So then call .show() on that toast everytime you want to call it.

Comment: Thanks guys got it from [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Spinner/src/com/android/example/spinner/SpinnerActivity.html)      From next time would do thorough research before posting. Thanks to all of you.